# Flipping between views has UITableView position issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UINavigationController within a UITabBarController. Within the navigation controller I have a ViewController that looks after flipping between two views using `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion` one of the views i am trying to show is a TableView.

The problem is when showing the TableView it is off position.

[image: Tableview showing off position]

and the flip view

[image: View in correct position]

I have tested flipping between two standard views without issue, it is only the TableView that shows off position. Also when the Tableview has more data then can be shown on screen the bottom rows are hidden by the Tabbar. It looks like the frame size is wrong but I am not sure how to proceed to fix the problem.

[Full test project and code can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/littlejon/FlipViewTest)

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you are using UIViewControllers (FlipSide and FlipMain) as subviews for FlipController which is itself a UIViewController.  Prior to iOS 5 this was [not supported](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/) and inevitably led to problems.  iOS 5 [adds support](http://invasivecode.tumblr.com/post/12383262201/container-view-controllers-part-i-one-of-the) for a view controller hierarchy but requires that you use the appropriate new methods.

You have a couple of choices: restructure the view controllers so they are not nested, rewrite the sub-controllers as UIViews, or use addChildViewController to add the subcontrollers.

I've forked and modified your original code [here](https://github.com/guyc/FlipViewTest) to illustrate that changing to UIViews resolves the problem with layout.

Comment: Hi Guy, thanks for the solution. So is the code you provided pre ios 5 compatible? One problem still remains, the bottom of the tableview is still obscured by the TabBarController. How would I fix this?

Comment: Yes, should be fine with iOS 4.  The problem with the TableView is just that I used an arbitrary (and very incorrect) height in the constructor of the UITableView.  Change the height from 600 to something more like 367.  See [this update in the fork.](https://github.com/guyc/FlipViewTest/commit/6a876c5cfda4da62a5e0429142aa3425dc111b2e).

Comment: Sorry I should have seen that, with a universal app what would be the programatic way to figure out the correct size? Sorry to spring the extra question! but i suppose that would be relevant to being able to have the app support rotation as well. Cheers.

Comment: Sure, you can avoid the use of an explicit size by setting the UITableView's frame to the frame of the container view before you start the animated transition.  You need to do this before the animation (and therefore before the tableview gets added to the container view) so that the animation shows the right size.  Once you do this, supporting orientations is trivial if you set the autoresizingMask on the UITableView.  [Here](https://github.com/guyc/FlipViewTest/commit/5b8324a2ef5b96954939b8855228e0c56f2be9d5) is a commit that removes the explicit size and supports rotation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer without the full code, but I would try playing with the "wantsFullScreenLayout" property of your view controllers. I say that because the offset seems to be 20px high, which corresponds to the status bar's height...

Let me know if this helped ;-)

Comment: I have added a full example project showing the issue. Not quite sure what to do with the "wantsFullScreenLayout" option. Thanks.